# Add some variables enteries to a specific line In R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set where each line (participant) has their ID

one participant completed half of the survey on a different dataset:

```
#first data set
ID<-c(999,998,997)
VAR1<-c(55,32,33)
VAR2<-c(44,22,99)
VAR3<-c(32,11,NA)
VAR4<-c(2,99,NA)
VAR5<-c(9,8,NA)
DF<-data.frame(ID,VAR1,VAR2,VAR3,VAR4,VAR5)

#participant missing answers
ID<-997
VAR1<-NA
VAR2<-NA
VAR3<-22
VAR4<-11
VAR5<-23
DF2<-data.frame(ID,VAR1,VAR2,VAR3,VAR4,VAR5)
```

how do I join the participant missing variables from DF2 to DF?

I did not find the answer to that in other questions and  did not succeed in doing it using `merge()` or `full_join()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DF)`), do a join with 'DF2' `on` the 'ID' column.  Get the other columns from both datasets ('nm1' - 'VAR' column names of first dataset) and as the columns are the same in second data, we use `i.` to differentiate, `mget` returns the values of columns from second in a `list`, use `fcoalesce` to colaecse corresponding columns in `Map` (such that it returns the first non-NA element) and assign (`:=`) back to the original data ('DF')

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- paste0("VAR", 1:5)
setDT(DF)[DF2, (nm1) := Map(function(x, y) fcoalesce(as.numeric(x), 
    as.numeric(y)), .SD, mget(paste0('i.', nm1))), on = .(ID), .SDcols = nm1]
```

-ouput

```
> DF
    ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
1: 999   55   44   32    2    9
2: 998   32   22   11   99    8
3: 997   33   99   22   11   23
```

Comment: and if DF2 is only: ```ID<-997
VAR3<-22
VAR4<-11
VAR5<-23
DF2<-data.frame(ID,VAR3,VAR4,VAR5)```?

Comment: @EladRefoua in that case you may need `nm1 <- intersect(names(DF1)[-1], names(DF2)[-1])`